# Why is my flutter text grainy with ShimmerEffect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I just imported flutter_animate: ^4.2.0+1 and implemented it in my code like this:

```
return Animate(
      onComplete: (controller) => controller.repeat(),
      effects: const [
        ShimmerEffect( //this is the problem
            color: Colors.white,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            delay: Duration(seconds: 2))
      ],
      child: Container(
          width: larghezza - 34,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(17),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                Colors.blue[900]!,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.purple[900]!
              ]),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: caricamento
              ? const LinearProgressIndicator()
              : Text(
                  abbonamentoAnnuale
                      ? "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.abc} $pa / ${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.anno.toLowerCase()}"
                      : "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.abc} $pm / ${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.mese.toLowerCase()}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 17),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )));
```

All the effects work correctly, except for the ShimmerEffect which grains the text inside the container. I attach the screen.
[image]

you probably won't see it very well but I assure you that the text is not clear. I specify that this only happens on iphone and not on ipad. I tried restarting, deleting and reinstalling the app but still the same problem.